# Why are the contours of a cone equally spaced?

Tags: conic-sections

Having trouble understanding what makes the contours of a cone equally spaced, where f(x,y) = root(x^2+y^2).

It would look something like this:
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/MultiVrbleFcns_files/image010.gif

Answer (score 0):

[$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is the distance between the point $(x,y)$ and the origin $(0,0)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem), so the contours are circles of given radius.